# mariadb galera bootstrapping fails

Tags: galera, mariadb-10.2

Starting point at the sandbox sb1, sb2, sb3:
All boxes identical.

A Fresh debian 9 install

mariadb 10.2

Galera3

build a test galera cluster with empty databases works fine.
All three nodes come up and work as expected.

then after stopping the test cluster
copy a LVM snapshot from a production mariadb server over to sb1

start mariadb server with standalone config to see if all databases and tables are correct.
(config I took from the server the data come from)

shutdown and restart the standalone to see if there is a problem.

All is fine, server starts and stops as expected.

Then change configs to fit galera

try to bootstrap with

## > galera_new_cluster

and that

https://pastebin.com/e5jm4Tec

is what happens.

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
#mysql settings
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0

max_connections=700
log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log


#------------------------------------------------------------
#galera settings
#------------------------------------------------------------

wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=512M"


datadir = /var/lib/mysql
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
#wsrep_sst_method = xtrabackup-v2

wsrep_cluster_name="tam_cluster"
 wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://162.255.86.161,74.208.250.175,162.255.86.145,93.115.26.72"

#for each machine different
wsrep_node_address="162.255.86.145"
wsrep_node_name="node_5"



!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

someone any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I made it work.

The problem is how the bootstrap script tries to start the server.

I tried on different machines and all had the same symptoms when trying to bootstrap the cluster using the script galera_new_cluster.

It has something to do with systemd, I guess.

bootstrap the new cluster "by hand" using

```
mysqld -umysql --wsrep-new-cluster
```

did the trick on all machines I tried.

And while starting the other nodes, it is also a good idea not use the "systemd way"

systemd mechanism has a timeout, and if your sync with the other nodes takes a bit longer, systemd spits out an error, but mysql keeps running and does what it is supposed to do.

It's not a bad thing, but it's kind of confusing.

So for now I recommend, starting the other nodes also "by hand"

```
mysqld -umysql
```

if all your nodes are synced, open another terminal and

```
mysqladmin -u<YourPrivilegedUser> -p shutdown
```

after that you can start and stop your nodes normally, using the "systemd way"

hope it helps.

Ju

Comment: Going deeper into that issue, it comes out, that it actually is a bug in mysqld. So the above should be seen as a temporary workaround rather than a solution.